How to obtain the AR1 parameter estimate from an fitted object using `mmrm`
I am struggling to obtain the AR1 parameter estimate after fitting a model in R using the mmrm package. Here is a working example:
library(lme4)
library(mmrm)

data("sleepstudy", package = "lme4")

dt <- sleepstudy
dt$Days <- as.factor(dt$Days)
m_mmrm <- mmrm(Reaction ~ Days + ar1(Days|Subject), 
                method = "Kenward-Roger",
                data = dt)

summary(m_mmrm)

which produces:
Formula:     Reaction ~ Days + ar1(Days | Subject)
Data:        dt (used 180 observations from 18 subjects with maximum 10 timepoints)
Covariance:  auto-regressive order one (2 variance parameters)
Method:      Kenward-Roger
Vcov Method: Kenward-Roger
Inference:   REML

Model selection criteria:
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance 
  1687.2   1689.0   -841.6   1683.2 

Coefficients: 
            Estimate Std. Error     df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   256.65      11.59  48.70   22.15  < 2e-16 ***
Days1           7.84       7.36 147.10    1.07  0.28820    
Days2           8.71       9.89 164.90    0.88  0.37994    
Days3          26.34      11.54 169.90    2.28  0.02366 *  
Days4          32.00      12.70 162.80    2.52  0.01274 *  
Days5          51.87      13.57 148.80    3.82  0.00019 ***
Days6          55.53      14.22 132.90    3.91  0.00015 ***
Days7          62.10      14.71 118.00    4.22  4.8e-05 ***
Days8          79.98      15.10 105.20    5.30  6.5e-07 ***
Days9          94.20      15.39  94.70    6.12  2.1e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Covariance estimate:
       0      1      2      3    4    5      6      7      8      9
0 2466.8 1972.3 1576.9 1260.8 1008  806  644.4  515.2  411.9  329.4
1 1972.3 2466.8 1972.3 1576.9 1261 1008  806.0  644.4  515.2  411.9
2 1576.9 1972.3 2466.8 1972.3 1577 1261 1008.1  806.0  644.4  515.2
3 1260.8 1576.9 1972.3 2466.8 1972 1577 1260.8 1008.1  806.0  644.4
4 1008.1 1260.8 1576.9 1972.3 2467 1972 1576.9 1260.8 1008.1  806.0
5  806.0 1008.1 1260.8 1576.9 1972 2467 1972.3 1576.9 1260.8 1008.1
6  644.4  806.0 1008.1 1260.8 1577 1972 2466.8 1972.3 1576.9 1260.8
7  515.2  644.4  806.0 1008.1 1261 1577 1972.3 2466.8 1972.3 1576.9
8  411.9  515.2  644.4  806.0 1008 1261 1576.9 1972.3 2466.8 1972.3
9  329.4  411.9  515.2  644.4  806 1008 1260.8 1576.9 1972.3 2466.8


I don't see the AR1 parameter anywhere there. I looked at the m_mmrm object itself:
> str(m_mmrm)
List of 21
 $ cov            : num [1:10, 1:10] 2467 1972 1577 1261 1008 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
 $ beta_est       : Named num [1:10] 256.65 7.84 8.71 26.34 32 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "(Intercept)" "Days1" "Days2" "Days3" ...
 $ beta_vcov      : num [1:10, 1:10] 137 -27.5 -49.4 -67 -81 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "(Intercept)" "Days1" "Days2" "Days3" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "(Intercept)" "Days1" "Days2" "Days3" ...
 $ beta_vcov_inv_L: num [1:10, 1:10] 1.00 1.68e-16 1.08e-16 -4.88e-01 1.79e-16 ...
 $ beta_vcov_inv_D: num [1:10] 0.0332 0.0332 0.0253 0.0149 0.0332 ...
 $ theta_est      : num [1:2] 3.91 1.33
 $ theta_vcov     : num [1:2, 1:2] 0.0103 0.0169 0.0169 0.0392
 $ neg_log_lik    : num 842
 $ formula_parts  :List of 8
  ..$ formula      :Class 'formula'  language Reaction ~ Days + ar1(Days | Subject)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  ..$ model_formula:Class 'formula'  language Reaction ~ Days
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  ..$ full_formula :Class 'formula'  language Reaction ~ Days + Subject
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  ..$ cov_type     : chr "ar1"
  ..$ is_spatial   : logi FALSE
  ..$ visit_var    : chr "Days"
  ..$ subject_var  : chr "Subject"
  ..$ group_var    : NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "mmrm_tmb_formula_parts"
 $ data           :'data.frame':    180 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ Reaction: num [1:180] 250 259 251 321 357 ...
  ..$ Days    : Factor w/ 10 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ Subject : Factor w/ 18 levels "308","309","310",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ weights : num [1:180] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ weights        : num [1:180] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ reml           : logi TRUE
 $ opt_details    :List of 3
  ..$ counts     : Named int [1:2] 19 19
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "function" "gradient"
  ..$ convergence: int 0
  ..$ message    : chr "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
 $ tmb_object     :List of 10
  ..$ par     : Named num [1:2] 0 0.5
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "theta" "theta"
  ..$ fn      :function (x = last.par[lfixed()], ...)  
  ..$ gr      :function (x = last.par[lfixed()], ...)  
  ..$ he      :function (x = last.par[lfixed()], atomic = usingAtomics())  
  ..$ hessian : logi TRUE
  ..$ method  : chr "BFGS"
  ..$ retape  :function (set.defaults = TRUE)  
  ..$ env     :<environment: 0x55deab1b27b8> 
  ..$ report  :function (par = last.par)  
  ..$ simulate:function (par = last.par, complete = FALSE)  
 $ tmb_data       :List of 16
  ..$ full_frame       :'data.frame':   180 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ Reaction : num [1:180] 250 259 251 321 357 ...
  .. ..$ Days     : Factor w/ 10 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..$ Subject  : Factor w/ 18 levels "308","309","310",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ (weights): num [1:180] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Reaction ~ Days + Subject
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Reaction, Days, Subject)
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:3, 1:2] 0 1 0 0 0 1
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Reaction" "Days" "Subject"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Days" "Subject"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:2] "Days" "Subject"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:2] 1 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Reaction, Days, Subject)
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:4] "numeric" "factor" "factor" "numeric"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Reaction" "Days" "Subject" "(weights)"
  ..$ data             :'data.frame':   180 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ Reaction: num [1:180] 250 259 251 321 357 ...
  .. ..$ Days    : Factor w/ 10 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..$ Subject : Factor w/ 18 levels "308","309","310",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ weights : num [1:180] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ x_matrix         : num [1:180, 1:10] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:180] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "(Intercept)" "Days1" "Days2" "Days3" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:10] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "contrasts")=List of 1
  .. .. ..$ Days: chr "contr.treatment"
  ..$ x_cols_aliased   : Named logi [1:10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "(Intercept)" "Days1" "Days2" "Days3" ...
  ..$ coordinates      : num [1:180, 1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..$ y_vector         : num [1:180] 250 259 251 321 357 ...
  ..$ weights_vector   : num [1:180] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ n_visits         : int 10
  ..$ n_subjects       : int 18
  ..$ subject_zero_inds: int [1:18] 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 ...
  ..$ subject_n_visits : int [1:18] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  ..$ cov_type         : chr "ar1"
  ..$ is_spatial_int   : int 0
  ..$ reml             : int 1
  ..$ subject_groups   : Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ n_groups         : int 1
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "mmrm_tmb_data"
 $ call           : language mmrm(formula = Reaction ~ Days + ar1(Days | Subject), data = dt, method = "Kenward-Roger")
 $ optimizer      : chr "L-BFGS-B"
 $ method         : chr "Kenward-Roger"
 $ vcov           : chr "Kenward-Roger"
 $ kr_comp        :List of 3
  ..$ P: num [1:20, 1:10] -0.02923 -0.00163 -0.00163 -0.00163 -0.00163 ...
  ..$ Q: num [1:40, 1:10] 0.05845 0.00325 0.00325 0.00325 0.00325 ...
  ..$ R: num [1:40, 1:10] 0.05845 0.00325 0.00325 0.00325 0.00325 ...
 $ beta_vcov_adj  : num [1:10, 1:10] 134.2 -27.1 -48.9 -66.6 -80.7 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "(Intercept)" "Days1" "Days2" "Days3" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "(Intercept)" "Days1" "Days2" "Days3" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "mmrm" "mmrm_fit" "mmrm_tmb"
 - attr(*, "converged")= logi TRUE

The best candidate for the AR1parameter seemed to be:
$ theta_est      : num [1:2] 3.91 1.33

However, since it's correlation, it should lie between -1 and 1 so that can't be it.
I was surprised that it isn't produced in the summary as it is in, for example, glmmTMB with the same data:
m_glmmTMB = glmmTMB(Reaction ~ Days + ar1(Days + 0|Subject), data = dt)
summary(m_glmmTMB)

which produced:
> summary(m_glmmTMB)

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name  Variance Std.Dev. Corr      
 Subject  Days0 2127     46.1     0.88 (ar1)
 Residual        212     14.6               
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18

so the AR1 parameter is 0.88. I also fitted a GEE model:
library(geepack)
m_gee <- geeglm(Reaction ~ Days, id = Subject, data = dt, corstr = "ar1")
summary(m_gee)

which produced:
Estimated Correlation Parameters:
      Estimate Std.err
alpha    0.856  0.0521

...which agrees nicely with glmmTMB
How do we obtain the AR1 parameter from the mmrm model ?

I think you can get this from appropriate transformations of the m_mmrm$theta_est component, but it's far from obvious. See here for a starting point, I think theta is probably (?) the log-SD of varepsilon and varphi respectively? (This question would also be worth posting as an issue at the mmrm issues list at some point, linking to here ... a quick search doesn't find any existing issues addressing this ...)

Thanks @Lynchian for the question! I think this came up before. In this case, if you just need the point estimate, the easiest just to look at the correlation matrix estimate:
cov2cor(VarCorr(m_mmrm))
Where you can read of the AR1 correlation in the 2nd row, 1st column e.g. (just below 0.8)
